# FutureWarning: pandas.tslib is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, python-3.x, ggplot2, python-ggplot

Im trying to import MTcars dataset but im getting this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvocx.png)

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning and it explains what it means and how to future-proof your code. I wouldn't worry too much about it, it looks like something `ggplot` needs to handle. In future, please do not post photos of your code, you should include it as text in the question.

Comment: Ok Thanks and sorry from next i will not post photos im new to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this warning this morning. I was able to get rid of it by following these steps:

1. Open command prompt and change directory to `.../site-packages/ggplot/`
2. Enter `utils.py` and the file will open in your default program for .py files
3. On line 81 change `pd.tslib.Timestamp` to `pd.Timestamp`
4. Save the file