# ANACONDA "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tslib'" in pandas python

Tags: pandas, anaconda

I would like to run below code but I received an error in my anaconda environment. How can I solve this issue in Anaconda? Please help!

Thank you.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from statsmodels.tools.eval_measures import rmse, aic
 from darts import TimeSeries
 from darts.utils.timeseries_generation import gaussian_timeseries, linear_timeseries
 from darts.models import RNNModel, TCNModel, TransformerModel, NBEATSModel, BlockRNNModel
 from darts.metrics import mape, smape
 from darts.utils.timeseries_generation import datetime_attribute_timeseries
```

[image]

After I tried

```
 conda uninstall pandas
 conda install pandas
```

Error message becomes :

[image]

Comment: pandas.tslib was deprecated, and removed in 0.24.0. If the module calling that is up to date, you will have to edit its source code

Comment: How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Depends on what called it. E.g. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196977/futurewarning-pandas-tslib-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-versio)

Comment: Did you also try `conda update darts`?

Comment: "PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix " I got error message

Answer (score 1):

Check the corresponding path, if you do not find  pandas._libs.tslib module then you would have to uninstall pandas and reinstall again.

```
conda uninstall pandas
conda install pandas
```

You can also check if the version of pandas you are using is consistent with the version of python

Comment: Are you getting the same error message or a different message?

Comment: first, check if the pandas version is  0.18. If yes please upgraded. In earlier versions of pandas, pd.isnull() can be used instead of pd.isna(), and the two are the same.

Comment: "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'isnull' " but I am just importing packages not coding pd.isna()