# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tslib' in darts model time series

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, tslib

I would like to use darts time series model with pandas dataframe. I tried to import below packages but this error message that I can't resolved. My pandas version is 1.3.4 that I can't lowered as suggested in some forums since then I need to lower the version of python also which is not allowed in anaconda. I also tried

```
 conda uninstall pandas
 conda install pandas
```

these did not worked also

[image]

Once I could not define Timeseries it is not possible to convert to timeseries to input darts model

```
 TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df)
```

please help thank you

Comment: `tslib` is depricated, so unless you downgrade your pandas, or if there's a newer version of darts that uses a newer version of pandas, you might be stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANACONDA "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tslib'" in pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70565969/anaconda-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-tslib-in-pandas-python) or this: [No module named 'pandas._libs.tslib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093020/no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslib)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this post. In anaconda environment create a new env with python 3.7.11 and make sure pandas not installed see the picture below:

[image]

then open jupyter in your new env make sure to install darts which has pandas dependency already so don't try to install pandas for darts type below lines in your notebook then you are ready to go

[image]